# iOS app only able to send 125 UDP messages?

Tags: ios, networking, udp

I am currently using the `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` library and successfully sending UDP messages to a server, however when 125 messages have been sent, the app stops sending messages but does not crash or throw any errors.

This is a problem as I am continuously sending messages to control a robots movement.

Here is the .m file for the view that is sending the messages.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#import "MovementVC.h"
#import "GCDAsyncUdpSocket.h"

@interface MovementVC ()

@end

@implementation MovementVC



- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
    f, r, l, b = false;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)RightTouchDown:(id)sender {
    r = true;
}

- (IBAction)RightTouchUpIn:(id)sender {
    r = false;
}

- (IBAction)RightTouchUpOut:(id)sender {
    r = false;
}


- (IBAction)ForwardTouchDown:(id)sender {
    f = true;
}

- (IBAction)ForwardTouchUpIn:(id)sender {
    f = false;
}

- (IBAction)ForwardTouchUpOut:(id)sender {
    f = false;
}


- (IBAction)LeftTouchDown:(id)sender {
    l = true;
}

- (IBAction)LeftTouchUpIn:(id)sender {
    l = false;
}

- (IBAction)LeftTouchUpOut:(id)sender {
    l = false;
}

- (IBAction)ReverseTouchDown:(id)sender {
    b = true;
}

- (IBAction)ReverseTouchUpIn:(id)sender {
    b = false;
}

- (IBAction)ReverseTouchUpOut:(id)sender {
    b = false;
}


-(void) sendUDPMessage: (NSString*)messageToSend
{
    GCDAsyncUdpSocket *udpSocket ; // create this first part as a global variable
    udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    NSData *data = [messageToSend dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [udpSocket sendData:data toHost:@"172.31.0.1" port:43211 withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
}


-(void) targetMethod:(id)sender
{
    if (r == TRUE)
    {
        [self sendUDPMessage: @"1"];
    }
    else if (l == TRUE)
    {
        [self sendUDPMessage: @"11"];
    }
    else if(f == TRUE)
    {
        [self sendUDPMessage: @"111"];
    }
    else if (b == TRUE)
    {
        [self sendUDPMessage: @"1111"];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I think you need to clean up after you send your message. There's probably a limit on the number of sockets that can be open and I don't see where you're closing them. Do this in the delegate methods udpSocket:didSendDataWithTag: or udpSocket:didNotSendDataWithTag:dueToError: and make sure you close the socket.

Comment: Or reuse the same socket: instead of allocating a new one each time, make the socket reusable by making it a @property of your MovementVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a pointer to your UDP socket and not persistently make new sockets, 1 should nearly always be enough.